# adding a column in dataframe an R date format

Tags: r, database

Question: Create a new reldate column in the movies data frame in R by converting the column release_date into R date format.

```
This is my code:
movies <-read.csv("C:/Users/phili/Downloads/movies500.csv")
movies
movies$reldate <- format(as.Date(movies$release_date),"%d/%m/%Y")
print(movies)
```

Unfortunatly the second code does not add a new column in as R date format.

[image]

If you can't answer my question directly, please use a very similar example

Answer (score 0):

In the future it would be helpful to see your data or similar example data instead of a screen shot.

Anyways, looks like there are three things that need to be fixed:

1. You probably don't need to use the `format()` function. What you might have wanted is the `format=` argument within the `as.Date()` function
2. `"%d/%m/%Y"` this part tells R what format to expect the dates should be in, your dates are year month, day, so the order is wrong
3. similarly your dates are separated by dashes not slashes

So it should look like this: `as.Date("2018-09-12",format="%Y-%m-%d")`

So in your example try this: `as.Date(movies$release_date,format="%Y-%m-%d")`

Or because one of the default for `as.Date()` is `"%Y-%m-%d"` you could probably just do `as.Date(movies$release_date)`